# Selecting and appending some data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, merge, contains

[image]

- Merging two files

1. I want to find letters in 'File1' by searching for letters in a column.
2. I want to find the row that contains the letters while searching for the letters found in 'File 1' in 'File 2'.
3. Selecting the row below the one found in 'step 2'.
4. Pasting 'step 3's' results into 'File1'.  -- File#1

*examples

```
import pandas as pd

File1 = pd.read_csv('sdfsdc.txt', sep=',', header = None)
File2 = pd.read_csv('sdfsdc.csv', 'r')

searchfor = list(File1[0])          #--> it's working:)
for x in searchfor:
    if File2[File2[0].str.contains(x)]:  #--> it's not working!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract` and `merge`:

```
pattern = f"({'|'.join(df1['A'].tolist())})"
match = df2['B'].str.extract(pattern, expand=False).shift()

out = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='A', right_on=match, how='left')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     A             B
0  JCW  Information2
1  MBM           NaN
2  COP  Information1
3  KVI           NaN
4  ECX  Information3
```

Setup:

```
data = {'A': ['JCW', 'MBM', 'COP', 'KVI', 'ECX']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'B': ['dflqksdhCOPdsds', 'Information1', 'hpotrtjgJCWee28', 
              'Information2', 'xrjzeoazECXeiz1', 'Information3']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Think you just have a little typo where it should be `df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)` and likewise for `df2`. But brilliant (and fast) answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JohnCollins. I fixed my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but is there a way I can do without pandas?

Comment: Without `pd.read_csv` too?